# Docker container bound to local volume doesn't update

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-volume

I created a new docker container for a Node.js app.

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM node:14

# app directory
WORKDIR /home/my-username/my-proj-name

# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# bundle app source

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3016
CMD ["node", "src/app.js"]
```

After this I ran:
`docker build . -t my-username/node-web-app`

Then I ran: `docker run -p 8160:3016 -d -v /home/my-username/my-proj-name:/my-proj-name my-username/node-web-app`

The app is successfully hosted at `my-public-ip:8160`.

However, any changes I make on my server do not propagate to the docker container. For example, if I `touch test.txt` in my server, I will not be able `GET /test.txt` online or see it in the container. The only way I can make changes is to rebuild the image, which is quite tedious.

Did I miss something here when binding the volume or something? How can I make it so that the changes I make locally also appear in the container?

Comment: What's the point on building an image with project and use project as volume? Can't get It, you might need to describe more on this, this is not the usual case for using docker. Mostly, you use **volume** to keep the datas you want, like database, logs ...etc, not whole project.

Comment: Maybe this is part of where my mental model of what's going on is breaking down. I have a project folder on the host, and "mirror" that project in a docker container. I want the container and host folders to be "synced" im terms of the files. I am doing this because I am using a shared server with many different projects/environments/dependencies. What is the typical approach here?

Comment: You might want to **edit** to share your whole complex enviroments. By the way, If your project looks that too complex and dependency to each others. What's your purpose to choose docker? Why not just use It directly?

Comment: Well project A could be a python machine learning stack, project B could be a nodejs web app, project C could be something graphics focused but using Python again, they are all different environments which could inadvertently cause dependency issues between users hence warranting encapsulation. Docker was the method that the sys admin setup to do this. My particular project doesn't have complex dependency issues. But when sharing a server with others we may inadvertently cause dependency issues if all work in the same environment

Comment: The second path in your `-v` option doesn't match the `WORKDIR` path in the Dockerfile; is that a typo in the question?  (I'd also just use a host Node environment here though.)

Comment: you need to bind the volume and also run the code with nodemon and that it how youll get automatic code propagation to your container

Comment: @DavidMaze this solution seemed to fix the problem, thanks!